# Find Positions of a Character in a Character array

Tags: java

I have to declare one charactor array, and i have to create two function i.e: one function which accept charactor and its check charactor position array and return first occurance charctor position.

second funtion which return last indx of that charactor.

Comment: So whats your problem?

Comment: You can convert the array to a string. `String s = new String(arr);`. then use those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class ExCharArray{

char array[] = {'s','x','z','y','s'};

public static void main(String args[]){

```
     locateIndex('s');
     getLastLocation('s');
```

}

public int locateIndex(char ch1){

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i]==ch1){

            return i;

        }
    }
    return  -1;
}


public int getLastLocation(char ch2){


    for (int i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

        if (array[i]==ch2){

            return i;

        }
    }

    return  -1;
}


        for (int i = ch.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

            if (ch[i]==chart){

                return i;

            }
        }

        return  -1;
    }
```